# Reverse JSON order or getting last two entries for iOS

Tags: ios, json

I am trying to get the latest updated entry in my JSON http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/trades/fetch but unfortunately the latest updated entries appear at the bottom and not at the top of the JSON list.  Here is my code

```
- (void)fetchedlatestData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];


    NSArray* bitcoinPrices2 = [json objectForKey:@"return"]; //2

    //Get the Last Price
    NSDictionary* latest = [bitcoinPrices2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary* latestPrice = [latest objectForKey:@"price"];



    NSLog(@"Data: %@", latestPrice);
```

By using `objectAtIndex:0`I can get the first entry, but how would I go about getting the very last entry as the index number would not be consistent and the amount of entries in the JSON is not a consistent number.  Would I need to reverse the order of the JSON when it comes in so the index is 0? How would I go about this? I am trying to get the last two "price" numbers to compare them and I am new to how JSON works.  Thanks

Comment: Note there is also a "date" field as a UNIX timestamp I could use but id need to return the greatest timestamp and that would be something I would try next if what I mentioned wont work.

Comment: You *could* read the spec for NSArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your items are in an array. You can get the count of items in the array with the `count` method. Once you have the count you can get any item you want. `lastObject` is also a shortcut method to get the last item.

```
    NSDictionary* last = [bitcoinPrices2 lastObject];
    NSDictionary* secondLast = [bitcoinPrices2 objectAtIndex:(bitcoinPrices2.count - 2)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-lastObject`:

```
NSDictionary* latest = [bitcoinPrices2 lastObject];
```

Comment: You can also get the count of the number of items in the array using bitcoinPrices2.count.  From there, you'd be able to get the last index.

Comment: I didn't know that existed, Thank you! How would I go about getting the second to the last "price" entry? Can I use lastObject in some way or would I need the count?

Comment: You'd have to go with `count`. Be sure to check if the array have more than 1 element though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use     [bitcoinPrice2 count] as well.

```
if ([bitcoinPrice2 count] > 0)
    NSDictionary *lastItem = [bitcoinPrice2 objectAtIndex:([bitcoinPrice2 count] - 1)];
if ([bitcoinprice2 count] > 1)
    NSDictionary *penultimateItem = [bitcoinPrice2 objectAtIndex:([bitcoinPrice2 count] - 2)];
```